# Using a depletion mode mosfet as a current limiting device

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current-limiting

I have recently discovered the exciting world of depletion mode mosfets. Curiously, even in [this document](https://www.ixys.com/Documents/AppNotes/IXAN0063.pdf), I found nowhere that a depletion mode mosfet could be used as a current limiting/inrush current limiting device. 
But this is strange, because what prevent us to use them like this:

[image]

or like this

[image]

(with a suitable heat sink of course) ?

To put flesh on bones, I have built a 800V, 10-20 mA PSU. I have a IXTY01N100D depletion mosfet, with 1000V breakdown voltage and 400mA current. It is not so easy to build a conventional inrush current limiter at this voltage. I wonder if I can use this transistor to limit the inrush current in the filtering output cap.

Comment: See figure 6, 8 and 9.

Comment: I vaguely remember this application was mentioned in the AoE vol 3.  I don't have it at hand to lookup now though. But you can definitely use depletion-mode MOSFETs as current-limiting devices.

Comment: Another thing about depletion-mode MOSFETs is that they can be used with V_GS > 0. See this IXYS App Note "Depletion-Mode Power MOSFETs and Applications" for more current source circuits with them: https://www.ixys.com/Documents/AppNotes/IXAN0063.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work. It's a common use for depletion FEts and several examples in the document you linked to use them as current sources.

Respect the Safe Operating Area though:

[image]

You can also make an AC current limiter with two depletion FETs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the ac current limiting circuit. Yes, it is well known that a depletion mosfet can be used as a current source, but it is not always immediate that 1+1 = 2, I mean, that a current source could be used as a current limiter. Even The Art of Electronics does not evoke depletion mosfets in the chapter related to current limiting. That is what I found strange.